# Update multiple rows from group by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table which looks like this

```
+----------------------------+
| id    | bdate     | item    |
+----------------------------+
|    1  | 20010101 |       1a |
|    1  | 20020202 |       1b |
|    1  | 20030303 |       1c |
|    2  | 20010101 |       1d |
|    2  | 20020202 |       1e |
+----------------------------+
```

i want to update bdate to today grouping by id where bdate is not max. so for above records result will look like this after executing query.

```
+----------------------------+
| id    | bdate     | item    |
+----------------------------+
|    1  | 20140106 |       1a |
|    1  | 20140106 |       1b |
|    1  | 20030303 |       1c |
|    2  | 20140106 |       1d |
|    2  | 20020202 |       1e |
+----------------------------+
```

I came up with results using temp tables but wanted to see If anyone has better suggestion.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way

```
UPDATE t
   SET bdate = GETDATE()
  FROM table1 t LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT id, MAX(bdate) bdate
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY id
) e
    ON t.id = e.id
   AND t.bdate = e.bdate
 WHERE e.id IS NULL;
```

Outcome:

```
| ID |      BDATE | ITEM |
|----|------------|------|
|  1 | 2014-01-06 |   1a |
|  1 | 2014-01-06 |   1b |
|  1 | 2003-03-03 |   1c |
|  2 | 2014-01-06 |   1d |
|  2 | 2002-02-02 |   1e |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba233/1)** demo

Comment: Well, nice to see that my solution is correct ;) I am guessing yours would be faster though, since you only update some of the lines (whereas I am updating all lines, I didn't want to use a WHERE clause)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you already built your table with the data (as per your example).

Let's say you name your table "MainTable", my take would be the following :

```
UPDATE MT
    SET bdate = CASE WHEN MT2.bdate IS NULL THEN GETDATE() ELSE MT2.bdate END
  FROM MainTable AS MT
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                      ID
                      ,bdate = MAX(bdate)
                   FROM MainTable
                   GROUP BY ID
               ) MT2
       ON MT2.ID = MT.ID
       AND MT2.bdate = MT.bdate
```

Now I would guess this logic should be very close to your temp table logic, except this is using a subquery (to work faster).
This also assumes the "Item" column isn't relevant for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT,BDate VARCHAR(10),Item VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
(1,'20010101','1a'), 
(1,'20020202','1b'),
(1,'20030303','1c'),
(2,'20010101','1d'),
(2,'20020202','1e')
```

**Query**

```
;WITH MaxDates
AS
  (
   SELECT *, rn = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY BDate DESC)
   FROM @t
  )
UPDATE MaxDates
SET BDate =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
FROM MaxDates
WHERE rn > 1

SELECT *
 FROM @t
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦══════════╦══════╗
║ ID ║  BDate   ║ Item ║
╠════╬══════════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ 20140106 ║ 1a   ║
║  1 ║ 20140106 ║ 1b   ║
║  1 ║ 20030303 ║ 1c   ║
║  2 ║ 20140106 ║ 1d   ║
║  2 ║ 20020202 ║ 1e   ║
╚════╩══════════╩══════╝
```